# Django delete old and new file before/after save new

Tags: python, django, database

My code in django view:

```
file_obj = MyFile.objects.get(id=5)
old_preview = file_obj.preview_path
form = FilePreviewForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=file_obj)

if form.is_valid():
    print old_preview # /upload/files/hahaha.jpg
    print file_obj.preview_path # ololo.jpg
    # you can see different objects - it's good!

    old_preview.delete() # I want delete only /upload/files/hahaha.jpg - old file

    print old_preview #
    print file_obj.preview_path #
    # you can see all files are deleted!!! it's so bad!!!
```

**Why is this happening?**

If I delete old file after saving, it will be the same. I checked!

UPD:
http://pastebin.com/vB0SRzze - it's WRONG

UPD2:
http://pastebin.com/bLNKbkLt

Comment: More context please? What type is `preview_path`? and what does `FilePreviewForm` do?

Comment: unrelated: `form.is_valid` is a function, so it should be `form.is_valid()`

Comment: http://pastebin.com/vB0SRzze

Comment: http://pastebin.com/bLNKbkLt - about preview_path and FilePreviewForm

Comment: @yedpodtrzitko correct this, thnx

Comment: @Saksow see update please)

Comment: hey @yedpodtrzitko

Comment: Please tell what is your indent. Are you changing a field ?

Comment: I want delete old file from media and change field by path to new file @itzmeontv

Comment: @cherry-girl posted one answer try it and tell me

Comment: Just save the form will change the field. Also if you want to delete that file, you have to do os.remove behind the scenes.

Comment: pls put the code directly into the question instead of linking multiple pastebins.

Answer (score 1):

You are not saving the form, try doing this first:

```
if form.is_valid():
    form.save()
```

Did it work ? Have a read [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/forms/modelforms/#the-save-method)

Comment: form save, but preview_path is null @Saksow

Comment: Did it change something ? can you post the new output ?

Comment: But I said: `try doing this FIRST` you have to save before print, it's the only way to understand what happened